# Adding CSS classes to elements (ITEMS) Inside a widget ELEMENTOR

Tags: css, wordpress, class, widget, elementor

I have a problem with adding css class inside an exiting widget of my theme on wordpress.
I need to put latepoint(BOOKING PLUGIN) Trigger class. **class="os_trigger_booking"**
I can't find any way to access html of this section so i can change the button class.

[the structure of widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsl0l.png)

The buttons I need to add class is inside this items.

[Options I Have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zd01p.png)

And this is the only options I have.

[Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mACxY.png)

I tried a lot of other plugins to access the html code of widget but I just didn't find anything that works. I need to find a way to trigger the booking plugin from a button that is inside a widget.